# javafx-src.zip is missing from the jre folder

Tags: java

I tried to add javafx library to Eclipse, but it said "Source not found". I've found out that the file javafx-src.zip, where source code of the library are supposed to be, is missing from the jre folder.

How to get the javafx-src.zip file?
java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS

Comment: Surely, you mean *JDK*, right? The JRE is not sufficient for development.

Comment: What version of the JDK are you attempting to install?  You should edit your question to provide the necessary relevant information required to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Java 11 does not include JavaFX. You need to get it separately see the [OpenJFX site](https://openjfx.io/) for more details.